# Outputting height of a pyramid

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for this coding exercise I have to input a number of imaginary blocks and it will tell me how many complete rows high the pyramid is.

So for example if I input 6 blocks...I want it to tell me that the height of the pyramid is 3. (3 blocks on the bottom, 2 above that, and 1 above that).

In my head I feel this would work similar to a Fibonacci pyramid so I based my code off of that.

```
blocks = int(input("Enter number of blocks: "))

for i in range(blocks + 1):
    for j in range(blocks + 1):
    height = j / 2
if height % 2 == 0:
    height = height / 2

print(f"The height of the pyramid: {height}")
```

This is what I have so far... If I do the number 6 or like 20 it works, but obviously if I do something like 1000 it isn't going to give me the result I want. I feel I'm pretty far off with my code.

Comment: Why do you have a nested loop just to compute `blocks / 2`?

Comment: Also, what does Fibonacci have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A pyramid of height `N` has `1 + 2 + … + N` blocks in it. This reduces to `N * (N + 1) / 2`. So you need to find the largest integer of the form `(N^2 + N) / 2` that is less than or equal to  your chosen number `blocks`. The quadratic is fairly simple: `N^2 + N - 2 * blocks = 0`, with roots at `N = floor((-1 +/- sqrt(1 + 8 * blocks)) / 2)`. Since `blocks` is a positive integer, the negative root will never apply in your case. You can use `int` for `floor` and `**0.5` for `sqrt` to get:

```
blocks = int(input("Enter number of blocks: "))
print(f'You can build a pyramid {int(0.5 * ((8 * blocks + 1)**0.5 - 1))} blocks high')
```

Answer (score 7):

```py
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))

height = 0

inlayer = 1

while inlayer <= blocks:

    height += 1
    blocks -= inlayer
    inlayer += 1

print("The height of the pyramid: ", height)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sum of block with n rows is n*(n+1)/2. For a matching block number floor(sqrt(2*x)) will give the correct result, with other numbers it can be 1 to large, so put the result into n*(n+1)/2 and if it is too large reduce by 1.

```
Height=floor(sqrt(2*x))
if(x<height*(height+1)/2) height=height-1
```

Comment: It's not quite 2x: the diagonal of the square is not double counted. 1 is clearly a matching number that does not work in your case

Comment: ? Floor(sqrt(2*1))=1 it does

Comment: Good point. Are you completely disregarding non-matching numbers like 2, 4, 5, etc?

Comment: Btw I can't comment on yours because I am new but it seems wrong if I applied it correctly https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Floor%280.5+*+%28%282+*+%28Sum+1+to+100%29+%2B+1%29%5E0.5+-+1%29%29

Comment: Why is there a sum in your formula?

Comment: To calculate the numbers of blocks in a pyramid with 100 levels

Comment: A pyramid with 100 levels has 5050 blocks. So yeah, my formula is a bit off. I fixed it now. It was `8 * blocks` in the square root, not `2 * blocks`.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clear what I do with non matching. But doing it with 1 formula is neater

Answer (score 2):

```py
blocks = int(input("Enter number of blocks: "))

for n in range(blocks): 
    if n*(n+1)/2 <= blocks: 
        height = n

print("The height of the pyramid is:",height)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think by other way:

Each row in the pyramid is the 'row' above + 1 and when finishing all rows then the sum of all rows are equal or 'bigger' which is the total number of blocks.

So, if you try by this method you have the follow code:

```
blocks = int(input("Enter number of blocks: "))
height = 0
by_row = 0
total = 0
for i in range(blocks):
    if blocks <= total:
        break
    height += 1
    by_row += 1
    total += by_row

print(f"The height of the pyramid:{height}")
```

So, it runs how you want but neglects the "Complete rows" part.

Answer (score 1):

First, I created a new variable called "Height" and assigned it with the value 0.

Then I created another variable called "Levels" to track the blocks used on each layer of the pyramid. I also assigned it a value of 0.

Why?:
The "Level" variable is necessary for use in comparing left over blocks to the last layer of the pyramid. Example - If you have 10 blocks left and your last layer was 10, you cannot create another layer because each one is supposed to have 1 block more.

When the variables "Level" and "Block" are the same, the loop is broken.

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
height = 0
levels = []

while blocks > 0:
    height += 1
    blocks -= height
    levels.append(height)
    if blocks <= levels[-1]:
         break

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
print(levels)
print(blocks)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
layer_block = 0
i = 1
height = 0
while True:
    layer_block = layer_block + i
    i = i + 1
    if layer_block > blocks:
        break
    height = height + 1
print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the blocks number is 6, the height is 3. But if the blocks number is 7, the bottom will be placed with 4 blocks. So the height will be only 2. Because 4+3 is 7.

If the blocks number is 20, the height will be only 5. Because the bottom is 6, and 6+5+4+3+2 gives us 20. And the height is only 5.

Here is the code:

```
blocks = int(input("Please input block numbers: "))

my_dict = {}

for num in range(1, blocks+1):
    my_dict[num] = (1 + num) * num / 2

for index, value in my_dict.items():
    if value == blocks:
        print(f"The height is {index}")
        break

    if value > blocks:
        _sum = 0
        bottom = index
        for num in range(index):
            _sum = _sum + bottom
            bottom -= 1
            if _sum >= blocks:
                print(f"The height is {num+1}")
                break
        break
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A pyramid with height n has 1 + 2 + ... + n blocks. That's also (n^2+n)/2.

Can you solve from here? You can use the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with because while building the pyramid if the remainder of the blocks are not sufficient you cannot complete the next/final layer/row.

Here's the code:

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))

height = 0

rows = 1

while rows <= blocks:

    height += 1
    blocks -= rows
    if blocks <= rows:
        break
    rows += 1

print("The height of the pyramid: ", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blocks = int (input("Enter the number of blocks: ")
height = 0
min_blocks = 0

for blokken in range (1, blocks + 1):
    if ((min_blocks + blokken) <= blocks):
        min_blocks = min_blocks + blokken
        height = height + 1
print ("The height of the pyramid: ", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
block =int(input()) 
for height in range(1,block):
    sum = sum+height
    if(sum == block):
     print("the height of pyramid:",height)
```

Comment: Provide explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I set the `count` variable to count the height. When only the `blocks` variable is greater than or equal to `1`, it runs the while loop.

In the while loop, there are conditional clauses to be separated from when `blocks == 1` and others. In the condition of the others, `count` plus  `1` for each iteration and set `total` variable as the normalized blocks to compare with the user-inputted `blocks`. When `total` is equal to `blocks`, `height` is `count` and escape while loop. Else if `total` is greater than `blocks`, `height` is equal to `count - 1` and escape while loop.

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
count = 1

while blocks >= 1:
    if blocks == 1:
        height = count
        break
    else:
        count += 1
        total =0
        for i in range(1, count+1):
            total += i
        if total == blocks:
            height = count
            break
        elif total > blocks:
            height = count -1
            break

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

hello guys this solution using both (for & while) loop

**Using `for` loop**

```py
blocks = int(input('Enter number of blocks:'))
j = 0
for i in range(1,blocks):       
    j = j + I
    if j > blocks:
        i = i-1
        break    
    height = I
    print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

**Using `while` loop**

```py
blocks = int(input('Enter number of blocks:'))
j = 0
i = 0
while i < blocks:
    i = i + 1
    j = j + I
    if j > blocks:
        i =i-1
        break    
    height = I
    print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution that I could derive:

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))                      
                                                                         
height = 0                                                                                                                              
while height < blocks:                                                   
    height += 1                                                          
    blocks -= height
                                                   
print(height)
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the total is 0 so if a user inputs say 6 blocks, definitely blocks are more than total in this case the else part executes.

The else statement keeps counting the height and summing it up to the total until it reaches the total number of blocks. It sums up the height because the row below is always height+1:  So what is basically happening is this: 1+2+3+....+n .

And The if block helps us to exit the loop. "blocks <=  total" , the less than (<) is because if the blocks are like 2 they are not enough to build a pyramid of height 2 so it should print the height as 1; so total should be less or equal to the blocks.

Hope this helps.

```
blocks = int (input("Number of blocks: "))
height = 0
total = 0

#loop until there are no more blocks    
while blocks:
   #this is the base condition which tells us when to exit the loop
   if blocks <= total:
      break
   else:
      height += 1
      total += height
print("Height is: ", height)
```

Comment: Add some text description about your answer (how it works)

Answer (score 0):

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
y = 0
x = 0
for x in range(0 , 99999999999999):
     if  y == blocks:
        height = x
        break
     elif y > blocks:
        height = x - 1
        break
     else:
        y += x  + 1
        height = x - 1
print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let,
**h** -> height of the pyramid
**n** -> number of blocks

**h** can be calculated using the equation **h = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8n))/2**. (Remove the floating value and consider only the integer part)

If you are intrested how the eaquation is derived, here is the explanation.

Here is the equation to calculate the height of a pyramid of n blocks :

**h(h+1)/2 = n**

Simplify the equation.

**h^2 + h = 2n**

Transforming it into quadratic equation of the form **aX^2 + bX + c = 0**, we get :
**h^2 + h -2n = 0**

Comparing **h^2 + h -2n = 0** with **aX^2 + bX + c = 0** we get :**a = 1, b = 1, c = -2n**

Put these value in the quadratic formula **X = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac))/2** (Ignoring -ve solution).
So,
**h = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8n))/2** -> final eqaution to calculate the height of pyramid with n blocks.

Rest is simple programming.

**PS: sqrt stands for square root.**

Answer (score 0):

I've come with this solution. I think is fairly simple, but does attend to the solution.

We have the height starting at 0 and  the blocks_out variable, which is every block that is added to the second, third, fourth... level of the pyramid.

So I made a while loop, which will stop when the number of blocks stay equal to the height meter or below it. It will prevent that the program complete a level without having enough blocks to do it. If it has, then the height will be under block's quantity and it will be able to complete a full level.

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))

height = 0
blocks_out = 1

while height < blocks:    
    blocks = blocks - blocks_out # blocks diminish, beginning with the first top block
    height += 1                  # put first block, first level done
    blocks_out += 1              # adittional block to each level that comes after


print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invert your pyramid, you're simply counting from 0 (height 0) and incrementing by 1. This also corresponds to the maximum blocks for each **"inverted" level**.
So:

- inverted height 1: 1 block (maximum)
- ...
- inverted height n: n blocks (maximum)

Using a while loop, this looks like a simple solution:

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
height = 0
while blocks > 0:             # as long as there are blocks
    if blocks - 1 >= height:  # remaining blocks vs number needed to fill the height level
        height += 1           # height is same as number of blocks in "inverted level"
    blocks = blocks - height  # remain after level completion
print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Comment: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NqUuSyCmI2EbYj_rVeIq2a5sBOGpp3TE?usp=sharing) (run the code in Google Colab)

Answer (score 0):

For this coding exercise, I simply had a top to bottom approach by increasing the each blocks layer by layer.

blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))

height = 0

while blocks > height :

```
  height +=1
  blocks = blocks - height
```

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
height=0
i=0
while n>i:
      i+=1
      n=n+1
      height+=1 
print("The height of the pyramid:", height)

thank you
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is 2.5 years old) with existing answers. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: Kept it as simple as possible.

```
height = 1
totalBlocks = 0

blocks = int(input("Enter the number of bricks:"))

while totalBlocks + height <= blocks:
    totalBlocks += height
    height += 1

print("The height of the pyramid is:", height - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

VERY new to IT... python is the first language I'm learning, but I'm pretty sure this works:

```
height = 0
width = 1
next_width = 1
        
while blocks >= next_width:
    blocks - width
    height += 1
    blocks -= next_width
    next_width += 1
           
print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

logic is putting an object in increasing order where top-level contains 1 and top-1 contains 2 and so on..Here passing array length and count=1 logic behind recursively call the same method until n>=count. For 1st call n=4 and count=1,for 2nd call n=3 and count=2 , for 3rd call n=1 and count=3 here condition fail and we return count-1.

```
/*Given n objects, with each object has width wi. We need to arrange them in a pyramidal way such that : 
    Total width of ith is less than (i + 1)th.
    Total number of objects in the ith is less than (i + 1)th.*/
public class Max_Height_Pyramid 
{
    static int pyramidHeight(int n,int count)
    {
        while(n>=count)
        {
            n=n-count;
            count++;
            pyramidHeight(n,count);
        }
        return count-1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] boxes= {10,20,30,50,60,70};
        int n=boxes.length;
        int count=1;
        int result=pyramidHeight(n,count);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))

height = 0

last_row_num = 0

LRN = last_row_num

while blocks > LRN:
    LRN = LRN + 1
    height = height + 1
    blocks = blocks - LRN
    if blocks <= LRN:
        break

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

This is what i used and it worked great try yourself :)
and it was fairly easy to understand.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
height = 0
used_blocks = 0

while blocks > 0:
    used_blocks += 1
    if blocks >= used_blocks:
        blocks -=  used_blocks
    else:
        break
    height += 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked in a way that is sufficiently different from the other (29) answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let **h** be the height of the pyramid, **f(h)** the number of blocks needed to construct a pyramid of height **h**, and **b** the current number of blocks we have. From the above, we are looking for an **h'** belonging to a set of heights, being the greatest height in the set that satisfies **f(h)** being less than or equal to **b**. The above idea can be summarized in mathematical notation as:

[image: equation1]

Where **f(h)** is equal to [image: equation2]

From the previous analysis we can create the following script to obtain the height **h'**

```py
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
height = 0 

# We iterate over the heights that meet the condition 
# in an increasing order until we find a height after 
# the maximum height that does not meet the condition.
while height * (height + 1) / 2 <= blocks: 
    # We obtain different heights from the set of heights 
    # that satisfy the condition
    height += 1  

# From the above, we can conclude that the previous height 
# is the height that satisfies the condition f(h) < b
height -= 1  

print("The height of the pyramid: ", height)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
blocks=int(input("Enter the number of blocks:"))
b=blocks
n=1
while n*(n+1)//2 <=b :
    h=n
    n=n+1
print("The height of the pyramid is", h)
```

Comment: This answer would benefit with an explanation of the code and what it does.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Comment: This question already has 28 other answers, and an accepted answer.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32480695)

Answer (score -2):

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))

height = 0
inlayer = 1
while inlayer <= blocks:
 height += 1
 blocks -= inlayer
 inlayer += 1

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Comment: Add some text description about your answer.

Comment: This is word-for-word identical to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852743/16775594), lacking only the explanation.