# Returns wrong output for the pyramid problem

Tags: python

For this coding exercise I have to input a number of imaginary blocks and it will tell me how many complete rows high the pyramid is.

For example, if I input 6 blocks, I want it to tell me that the height of the pyramid is 3 (3 blocks on the bottom, 2 above that, and 1 above that).

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
height=0
count=1
while(blocks>1):
    for i in range(0,count):
        blocks -= 1
    count +=1 
    height += 1

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

It works for 6, but for 1000, it should return 44 but instead I get 45! What's wrong with my code?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Welcome to SO! If the number of blocks are 7, what's the height?

Comment: You don't need to go until 1000 to see that it's wrong. It's wrong even for `blocks = 1`.

Comment: I think `while(blocks>1):` should be `while(blocks>=1):`

Comment: @mkrieger1 haha, nice way to put it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outputting height of a pyramid in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292099/outputting-height-of-a-pyramid-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation with just a while loop

```
number=1000
count=0
while number >= count:
    count +=1
    number -= count

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add to the count before the for loop and add an ='s.

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
height=0
count=1
while(blocks>=1):
    count +=1
    height += 1
    for i in range(0,count):
        blocks -= 1


print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded this myself and found out that many variables are not required.
Also I have added some comments for you :)

```
blocks = int(input("Enter the number of blocks: "))
# Suppose user enters 3 blocks

layer = 0

while(layer<blocks): #0<3; 1<2; 1<0->is false, so goes to else
    layer+=1 #0+1=1; 1+1=2; 
    blocks = blocks - layer #3 = 3-1 = 2; 2-2 = 0
    print("Layer added: ", layer)
else:
    print("Work stopped! As the blocks are finished for next layer :)")
    
height = layer #stores last occurrence of layer added, as each layer is height

print("The height of the pyramid:", height)
```

Now, if you read the comments in my program carefully, you will get the entirety of what's required to be done.
Feel free to ask back.